# Console error while running react js sample web app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, jsx

I am new to React js and was trying my hands on a very simple hello react kinda web app. But while running, ended up at below error in console.

**Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.**

Browser: Chrome version 46.0.24

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello React!</h1>
                document.getElementById('app')
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please point out what could possibly be going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we can't help you without code :)

Comment: @martriay Have a look at the updated question with code. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `cdns` you are using for the library files are unreachable.

[image: Unreachable CDNs]

From the **[React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html)** page these are the working links for the `cdn`:

https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js

https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.min.js

https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js

Second, there should be comma after `<h1>Hello React!</h1>` that separates **what should be rendered** to **where** .

So your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello React!</h1>,
                document.getElementById('app')
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. Realized it later. Issue got fixed with the correct cdn. Thanks

Comment: @user3400887 If the solution worked, please mark the answer as Correct.

Answer (score 2):

You links are broken. Use these updated links

Use domain `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` instead of `cdnjs.cloudfare.com`

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js
```