# Have an error with a web application

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have created a webpage application using python, flask and html. I have created a simple index page which should give me access to the other webpages but everytime I run the app this is the error I get:

> calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts
>   a shadow root is deprecated.

Flask app:

```
import flask as fl
import itertools as it

app = fl.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def root():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route("/perms", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def perms():
    perms = [''.join(p) for p in it.permutations(fl.request.values["userinput"])]
    return '\n'.join(perms)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Music Store</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="addToStore.html">Add</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Store</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h3>What is My Music Store?</h3>
  <p>This is a single web application that allows a user store their favorite songs and artist so they never forget a song.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code? Otherwise it's a bit hard to help you.

Comment: ok good start and now show your Python code...where the actual problem might be..

Comment: The javascript error doesn't seem to have any relation with the code you have included in your question. Are you sure this is not caused by some browser plug-in instead? In the browsers javascript console you should be able to get a reference to where the error was triggered. ShadowRoot is an experimental javascript feature that is not supported by most web browsers. So it has nothing to do with Flask.

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently the problem could go a little bit deeper than your code. It's most likely that you are unable to load your **JavaScript** libraries while your are trying to manipulate **DOM** elements. In your code try structuring it like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

While putting the `bootstrap.min.css` at the bottom so it loads after the JavaScript libraries. I think you can find a better in depth explanation on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062894/console-error-while-running-react-js-sample-web-app).

Comment: thank you very much for your insight and advice. I will be more careful next time I will ask a question. I have implemented the code you have provided me but I am afraid it did not solve my issue but I am greatful for your help.